# How to get the weather description from OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, openweathermap

I am trying to get the weather description in French from the `OpenWeatherMap` API but I am stuck.

What am I doing wrong please?

```
var urlBase = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=";
var apiKey = "&appid=xxx";
var unitsParam = "&units=metric";
var language = "&lang=fr";
var url = urlBase + cityCode + unitsParam + language + apiKey ;

startWebRequest (url, function(status, type, content) {
  var data = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log(data);
  setScreen('screen2');
  setText("label1",data.name);        
  setText('label2',data.main.temp);
  setText('label3',data.main.feels_like);
  setText('label4',data.weather.description[0]);
```

I get an `undefined` error and I am stuck.

> TypeError: data.weather.description is undefined.

Could you please look at my code and help me out?

Comment: When you log data, is the description in there?  That’s the first thing I would check.

Comment: @lexybb if you found one of our answers to work for you could you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the returned object you should access the description this way: `data.weather[0].description`

Answer (score 1):

According to the API docs, `description` is a `string`, not an `array`. But also you weather key is an `array`.

So to correctly access the `description` as you've intended, you need to do this:

```
data.weather[0].description
```

Not:

```
data.weather.description[0]
```

But do note, you might have issues if the `weather` array is empty.

Doing what I recommended above will solve your `TypeError` that you're experiencing.

If you're having problems with the `setText` value being `undefined`. Just use an empty string as a fallback.

Like this:

```
setText('label4', data.weather[0] ? data.weather[0].description : '')
```

Comment: thanks Barry! that's what I did at first  data.weather.description but then i got this error :setText() text parameter value (undefined) is not a uistring.ERROR: Line: 34: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: @lexybb I've updated my answer to help out with that